# Formula to to Fill missing numbers as zeros

Tags: excel

if column as data like 10 digits in one row (A1) , 2,3 ,...9 in other rows  and a blank , I need write a formula so that if there are 10 chars it should return what it is and if there are less that 10 it should fill remaining chars till it matches 10  with zeros and if it has blank cell it should return blank.

=if(a2<10,if(count(a2)+right(a2,9))) , In this case there is only 1 char in a2.

Comment: Do you mean leading zeros? You can use a number format. If you need a formula you can use `TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

Formula:

```
=IF(A1="","",TEXT(A1,"0000000000"))
```

Or set a custom number format:

[image]

Comment: I have 100 rows, a1 may have 2 chars, a2 may have 10 chars, a3 may have 4 chars but my count should match  10 example : if i have 248 then my should return 0000000248 . Example 2 i have ‘2’ it should return 0000000002 , example 3 : if its blank ut should return blank.

Comment: I've fixed the formula. The custom number format works if you're only changing how the numbers look to users.

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark my answer as correct to show the question has been resolved. Otherwise, please clarify your issue further. Thanks.